# Sound plays multiple times at once

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I'm having trouble with sound in Flash. I may have went about coding the wrong way, because most of my codes are on frames.

So, I have these two variables

```
var outsideDay:Sound = new daysong();
var outsideNight:Sound = new nightsong();
```

And I want to play these songs on a specific frame. However, the sounds play sporadically, like 50 times at once. I think it's because I have other codes that link to the frames with a Enter_Frame function. How can I get the sounds to loop and not play multiple times at once?

Answer (score 1):

Have you dropped the sound anywhere on the timeline in any frame? If so remove that frame.

Also, if you have your code declared on a keyframe that does not have a `stop();` call on it, likely it is hitting that frame over and over again, when it "enters" it. Try adding `stop();` either at the beginning of your code or at an ending key-frame, wherever it makes most sense for your project.

After trying those two things, another method I have learned to love that may come in handy is:

```
flash.media.SoundMixer.stopAll();
```

This will stop all sounds so that whatever sounds you start to play after making this call will not have other previously started sounds to contend with.

[This sound tutorial](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sound/) may also be of use to you.

Let us know how it goes, or if any of this stuff helped.

Comment: Yes, I have the stop code on the keyframe. I forget to mention that I'm working on a game that involves clicking buttons and such. All the buttons have Soudmixer.stopAll(); so that works, however the sound still plays multiple times at once.

Comment: Put a trace("clicked"); in your click handlers and check if it is getting called multiple times on a single click. Also verify that the timeline within the button(s) does not have a layer with any sound on it.

Comment: The buttons aren't getting called multiple times, and there are no sounds on any keyframes.

Comment: Better question, is there another Event I can use besides ENTER_FRAME that I can use to activate the sound?